# Connecting a mathematical solution to a differential equation with it's physical solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

I have seen this question in a neuroscience course:
[image]

It is given after the lecture with [these](http://courses.edx.org/c4x/EPFLx/BIO465x/asset/slides_lecture1.2.pdf) and [these](http://courses.edx.org/c4x/EPFLx/BIO465x/asset/slides_lecture1.3.pdf) slides.

I have no background in physics. However, I do know how to solve a differential equation of this form. It is a linear first order differential equation.

So, here is my solutions for the cases of $I=0$ and $I=const=I_0$:
[image]

However, I can't connect the two solutions (mine and the one given in the course).

In other words, how come all 3 answers are correct?

1. where does the $T(t-s)$ come from?
2. where does the 9.5 come from?
3. How can I get from the question that I have to integrate from $0$ to $t$ or from $0$ to $infty$?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$9.5-u_{rest}$ can be accounted for by your constant $C_0$. Since you already can see why the third option is correct (actually directly from the question by using the integrating factor), you can perform a substitution to get the first option, and then add the homogenous solution to get the second option.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. Together with your clue, I also tried assuming $I(t)=I_0$ is constant. and then calculate $u$ and $u'$ and substitute. Since the question is if this solutions are possible, this was also good enough..

Comment: @user135172: If I understood you rightly, your method of assuming $I$ to be a constant function is not correct, because the question implicitly asks for which options are solutions **for any function $I$ such that $I(t) = 0$ for any $t < 0$**. So it is clearly not enough to check for particular $I$.